# Progress Output when saving Event Logs

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm not sure if this is even possible or if there is a better way to do this, but I would really like to display the progress of this operation. I'm still new with C# development, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far. I would love to update my progressbar accordingly:

```
async void EventLogs(string exportPath, string log)
{

    await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                EventLogSession eventlog = new EventLogSession();
                eventlog.ExportLogAndMessages(log,
                    PathType.LogName,
                    "*",
                    exportPath + " " + log + ".evtx",
                    false,
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
                    );
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {

            }
            catch (EventLogNotFoundException)
            {

            }
            catch (EventLogException)
            {

            }   
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is there to track?  You have two lines of code.  You really need to report when EventLogSession eventlog = new EventLogSession(); is complete?

Comment: I guess if i could figure out how to count the entries in the event log i could track

Answer (score 2):

Async and await support progress indication via `IProgress<T>`, as described in the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx). Note that `Progress<T>` handles UI dispatching for you, so no messing with `Dispatcher` is necessary.

Unfortunately, `ExportLogAndMessages` does not support progress reporting. So, if you want some meaningful progress, you'll need to figure out how to partition the event log messages. You can then call the method for different segments of the partition, calling `IProgress<T>.Report` in-between calls.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

1. You can use BackgroundWorker, it has specific features that allow you to report progress and it handles the ui dispatching for you.
2. If you insist on using the newer api of async await and Tasks, you will need to make sure to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() to call your code in the UI thread and not the Task thread, then you will have to use data binding to set a property with INotifyPropertyChanged if you use MVVM  or just access a reference of the ProgressBar if you are doing quick and dirty UI.

EDIT:

If you are not sure about the progress calculation, just use it with his IsIndeterminate property.

HIH

Ariel

Comment: I would like to use the new api with the async I have done this and been successful, but I guess I am not sure how to calculate the progress